# android retrofit can not send post request

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to use this web service:
http://amar.096313.ir/info/app/check_version/check_version.php
 Sending and receiving information by postman and HttpURLConnection method is done correctly, but with retrofit, the "503 Service Unavailable" is returned.

Comment: We can't guess the problem. please post your code too.

Comment: It would most probably be an issue with backend. Did you try with postman?

Comment: Please check your annotation  in service may be it is GET instead of POST. Otherwise please post your code

Comment: check your header